# Wie sagt man "to some extent" Auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, adverb

> Ich habe dieses Problem gewissermaßen gelöst.

```
I solved this Problem to some extent.
```

Wie sagt man `to some extent`auf Deutsch? Ich habe hier drei weitere Wörter der selben Bedeutung: `einigermaßen`, `ansatzweise` und `halbwegs`. Können sie wechselzeitig verwendet werden?

Comment: soooo... you want to compare *"gewissermaßen"*, *"einigermaßen"*, *"ansatzweise"* and *"halbwegs"* in respect to which translates *"to some extent"* better??

Comment: Ich möchte wissen, welches Adverb hier in diesem Kontext passt. :)

Comment: Im obigen Kontext hieße *gewissermaßen*, daß du wahrscheinlich ein anderes Problem gelöst hast, oder ein ähnliches, oder einige Randbedingungen außer Acht gelassen hast, was dummerweise deine Lösung völlig unbrauchbar macht. "einigermaßen" hieße, du hast es mehr schlecht als recht gelöst. "ansatzweise" würde man so interpretieren, daß du schon einmal in Erwägung gezogen hast, mit der Lösung zu beginnen.

Comment: @ingo: Soll "mehr schlecht" nicht "schlechter" sein?

Comment: @karoshi "mehr schlecht als recht" ist eine stehende Redewendung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich würde je nach Situation "bis zu einem gewissen Grad" oder "teilweise" sagen.

Answer (score 4):

*Gewissermaßen* bedeutet so viel wie *sozusagen*, *quasi*.
Hast du ein Problem *gewissermaßen* gelöst, kann das bedeuten, dass es noch nicht ganz gelöst ist, aber fast. Es fehlt wahrscheinlich nur noch ein kleiner Baustein.

*Gewissermaßen*, *sozusagen* als auch die Phrase '*bis zu einem gewissen Maße*' haben jedoch auch noch eine zweite Konnotation, die meines Erachtens in diesem Kontext überwiegt. Ist ein Problem *gewissermaßen* oder *sozusagen* gelöst, ist das Problem nicht wirklich gelöst, sondern nur ein Weg gefunden worden, dass das Problem nicht mehr auftritt. Man arbeitet also drum herum, also ein Workaround.
*Quasi* kann diese andere Bedeutung auch tragen, in diesem Kontext überwiegt hier aber meinem Empfinden nach immer noch erstere Bedeutung.

*Einigermaßen* passt im Kontext nicht ganz, auch wenn es durchaus *fast* bedeuten kann. Das Wort verwendet man beispielsweise eher, wenn man sagt, dass es einem 'einigermaßen gut geht'. Es geht einem nicht richtig gut, aber fast.
Im gegebenen Kontext klingt es eher wie 'es ist zwar gelöst, aber ich bin damit nicht zufrieden'.

*Ansatzweise* bedeutet, dass du nur einen kleinen Teil gelöst hast. Im Ansatz halt, wie das Wort ja besagt. *Ansatzweise* ist *to a lesser extent* im Vergleich zu *to some extent*, falls du verstehst, was ich meine.

*Halbwegs* und *teilweise* sind für mich hier gleichbedeutend. Während Ersteres suggeriert, dass man die Hälfte geschafft hat, gibt Letzteres keine wirklich Information zu erkennen. Dennoch interpretiere ich es gleichermaßen.

Abgesehen von *einigermaßen* können alle diese Wörter im Kontext sinnvoll verwendet werden, auch wenn man sich deren Bedeutungsunterschiede bewusst sein sollte.

Comment: `Gewissermaßen gelöst` can also mean `im Prinzip gelöst` with a positive connotation. Maybe only the details of the solution are missing.

Comment: @Toscho Good catch. 'Im Prinzip' is another synonym here.

Comment: Seltsam, in meinen Ohren klingen "einigermaßen, gewissermaßen und ansatzweise" in Bezug auf Problemlösungen allesamt nach euphemistischer Verschleierung für die Tatsache, daß das eigentliche Problem ungelöst ist.

Answer (score 1):

Einigermaßen, ansatzweise und halbwegs - alle drei passen ziemlich gut.

Gewissermaßen passt m.E. nicht, denn es sagt nicht, dass das Problem teilweise gelöst wurde, sondern in gewisser Hinsicht.

Das kann ein Workaround sein, kann aber auch bedeuten dass das wesentliche gelöst ist, nur der Feinschliff fehlt noch, wie in: "Der Speicher ist ausgebaut, das Werkzeug muss nur noch weggeräumt werden." Dazu würde man m.W. nicht sagen "to some extend".